# MySQL, SQL query over several rows

Tags: php, mysql, key-value, key-value-store

I have a table called clothes_properties and some of the rows looks like this:

```
id  product_id  property_name   property
55  189000      color           blue
56  189000      type            tshirt
57  189000      size            medium
58  189001      color           red
59  189001      type            tshirt
60  189001      size            medium
```

I would like to create a SQL query that is able to select the correct product_id from what the user searches. So if the user searches for tshirt and medium, I want the SQL query to return: 189000 & 189001. And if the user searches for tshirt and blue I only want this product id to be returned: 189000. How can I create an SQL query that does this?

Comment: I believe your table is badly structured. Each property name should be a different field containing according property entries.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of table is often called a key / value store. It's a valid way to handle an extensible list of properties, but can be a bit of a hassle to use.

A query like this will give you the `product_id` values in in order of how well they match your list of criteria, best match first. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7870b5/2/0)

```
select count(*) matches, product_id
  from prop
 where property in ('tshirt','medium')
 group by product_id
 order by 1 desc
```

This query is ignorant of the difference between size, color, and type, though.

If you want to match size, color, etc, precisely, it gets a little more complex. You need to start with a query that pivots your key/value property table -- turns the rows into columns. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7870b5/3/0)

```
select id.product_id, 
       color.property color,
       type.property type,
       size.property size
 from (select distinct product_id from prop) id
 left join prop color on id.product_id = color.product_id and color.property_name = 'color'
 left join prop type on id.product_id = type.product_id and type.property_name = 'type'
 left join prop size on id.product_id = size.product_id and size.property_name = 'size'
```

You then need to treat this as a virtual table and query it, possibly like so. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7870b5/4/0)

```
select *
  from (

        select id.product_id, 
               color.property color,
               type.property type,
               size.property size
         from (select distinct product_id from prop) id
         left join prop color on id.product_id = color.product_id and color.property_name = 'color'
         left join prop type on id.product_id = type.product_id and type.property_name = 'type'
         left join prop size on id.product_id = size.product_id and size.property_name = 'size'
         ) allprops
 where size='medium' and color = 'blue'
```

Many developers and dbas will create a view looking something like `allprops` to make this a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to completely ignore the `property_name` column?

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM   clothes_properties
WHERE  property IN ('tshirt', 'medium');

SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM   clothes_properties
WHERE  property IN ('tshirt', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select product_id
from clothes_properties
where property_type = 'type' and property = 'tshirt' or
      property_type = 'size' and property = 'medium'
group by product_id
having count(distinct property_type) = 2;
```

Note: the `distinct` is not needed if you don't have duplicate property types for a give product.

If you wanted something generic, you might use:

```
select product_id
from clothes_properties
where property_type = 'type' and (property = $type or $type = '') or
      property_type = 'size' and (property = $size or $size = '') or
      property_type = 'color' and (property = $color or $color = '')
group by product_id
having count(distinct property_type) = (($type <> '') + ($size <> '') + ($color <> ''));
```

Comment: I tried your first example and it works perfectly when testing it on an small table. Will try it on a bigger table now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

`SELECT DISTINCT(product_id) FROM clothes_properties WHERE property IN ('tshirt','medium')
group by product_id
having count (distinct property) = 2`